# How does C multiply two float numbers?

Tags: c, assembly, floating-point, multiplication

If we have two integers numbers, 5 and 6, for example, we can just do

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   number += 6;
```

That is the same thing as

```
number = 5*6;
```

But, how does it works for float numbers? I searched in a lot of forums and couldn't find the answer. Does anybody know how C makes two floats be multiplied?

Comment: I don't know of any hardware architecture that doesn't have multiply instructions, so why should a C compiler turn a  multiplication into a loop?

Comment: @UnholySheep Some artificial academic ISA's might have.

Comment: @UnholySheep the old PIC microcontrollers. I'm sure many of them are still in use in education.

Comment: Even if it hasn't got a multiply instruction (simple old CPU) you don't multiply by an adding loop but by bit-shifting. But you don't have to worry, coding in C will do it for you.

Comment: It depends on the architecture the compiler targets. You can use godbolt.org to see how it works with different compilers on whatever system they are using. In [this case](https://godbolt.org/z/4Yd37zYTb) it is converted to a single assembly instruction.

Comment: Ask your compiler to output assembly instructions. That might help you understand.

Comment: c doesn't multiply, the CPU does. mostly by using lookup tables IIRC

Comment: Note that the loop is not equivalent to the multiplication expression if the first term is negative.

Comment: @UnholySheep Even as recently as SPARCv7, multiply instructions were a bolt-on.

Comment: You at least start with the bit-shifting: eg: `x*= 10;` -> `x = x >>3 +x+x;`  You can see why people prefer the former.

Comment: Pretty sure that the architecture that does not have multiplication instruction will not have a hardware floating point support. So it will be emulated in the software. There are ways to perform gloating point calculations using only integer arithmetic, and you are doing on of them when doing the "long" multiplication or division with pen-and-paper.

Comment: So, the float numbers product function is already been written at the computer memory, is that so? I also think that, but I just want to make sure about it. My guess is that this function is solved by logic circuit's algorythms.

Comment: 100 years ago they used to teach us multiplication by hand, [example](https://www.splashlearn.com/math-vocabulary/multiplication/long-multiplication) The same thing goes for binary multiplication, it doesn't need a loop.

Comment: @DiegoReis, it is contrary to convention here to modify the question title to indicate that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.  Instead, your options include clicking the check mark next to one of your answers and just doing nothing.  Under some circumstances (but not the present ones) you could also just delete your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays, floating-point operations are performed as single instructions in the [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit)'s repertoire, and no software implementation is necessary.

Anyway, you can easily imagine that a floating-point multiply is performed by

- multiplying the mantissas, viewed as integers with proper scaling;
- add the exponents;
- combine the signs.

Extra housekeeping needs to be done for special numbers, such as zero.

Comment: That's makes sense! I totally forgot about the ALU and the binary expressions from eletricity circuits. Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 1):

> how does C multiplies two numbers?

First, the compiler will determine if there is a constant involved, so maybe it will do a shift or shift and add.

If there is no constant or the constant is too large, and if the processor doesn't have a multiply instruction and no multiply hardware then the C compiler will use a library routine to do the job.  Sometimes these library routines are called intrinsics, or helpers.  These are hand-written in assembly for performance, and the compiler will know if non standard calling conventions are used.  Non standard conventions can increase efficiency in such situations, for example knowing that certain otherwise scratch registers will be preserved.

Floating point works the same, if there are no floating point instructions and no floating point hardware: special library routines hand-written in assembly for performance, possibly with non-standard calling conventions.

When there are instructions in the instruction set, but there's no hardware implementation for them (which happens on the low end of processors when their higher end siblings do have the hardware), then those instructions will generate a hardware exception, which will allow software to emulate the instructions and registers as needed.  Typically, this is less efficient than knowing up-front that the hardware doesn't have these operations — it would have been better to call library functions instead, but this approach of emulation by exception allows execution of "normal" code that expects the instructions & registers.